# Difference between 3 methods of detecting true in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

It does seem to be a big deal but are there any significant differences in following 3 methods of counting number of true items?

```
#lang racket

(define (counttrue . vars)
  (length (remove* (list #f) vars))    )

(define (counttrue2 . vars)
  (define c 0)
  (for ((item vars))
    (when item (set! c (add1 c))))
  c    )

(define (counttrue3 . vars)
  (count (lambda(x) x) vars)    )
```

They all produce identical results but is there any reason why a particular one should or should not be chosen?

Edit: on using time function, following results are obtained with 3 functions above and 2 each from answers by @ChrisJester-Young and @Sylwester :

```
"---------- counttrue ------------"
cpu time: 751 real time: 751 gc time: 16
"---------- counttrue2 ------------"
cpu time: 946 real time: 947 gc time: 10
"---------- counttrue3 ------------"
cpu time: 456 real time: 457 gc time: 8
"---------- counttrue_chris1 ------------"
cpu time: 726 real time: 727 gc time: 9
"---------- counttrue_chris2 ------------"
cpu time: 595 real time: 595 gc time: 8
"---------- counttrue_sylwester1 ------------"
cpu time: 543 real time: 544 gc time: 7
"---------- counttrue_sylwester2 ------------"
cpu time: 515 real time: 515 gc time: 7
```

Hence, the "count lambda" method is the fastest.

Comment: I could say the lambda would be the best way to go because it is the easiest to read (to me)... But you should try (time (counttrue...)) to see which one excels in performance

Comment: What's your guess?

Comment: I believe the lambda is quickest

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I have included time info in question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `count` version is probably the most idiomatic (except I'd write it as `(count identity items)`). Furthermore, the `set!` version is definitely not idiomatic Racket, and Racket doesn't optimise its use, as you can see from your timing tests.

Here are a couple of alternatives for your timing pleasure:

1. Using `for` comprehensions:

   ```
   (for/sum ((x (in-list items)) #:when x) 1)
   ```
2. Manual looping:

   ```
   (let loop ((sum 0)
              (items items))
     (cond ((null? items) sum)
           ((car items) (loop (add1 sum) (cdr items)))
           (else (loop sum (cdr items)))))
   ```

Comment: I have included your functions in the timing info in my question.

Answer (score 2):

They are just different ways of doing the same. All of them are O(n) so they don't differ much in time. Some of them waste a little memory by having an intermediate list but I think you have wasted more time on comparing these than you ever going to get back by picking the fastest one. I'd go for the one that is shortest and to the point, based on your third:

```
(define (count-true . args)
  (count values args))
```

It's actually just a specialized foldl:

```
(define (count-true . args)
  (foldl (lambda (val sum) 
           (if val (add1 sum) sum)) 
         0 
         args))
```

Both `count` and `foldl` are implemented with named `let` in `#!racket`.